# What kind of device is this?

Tags: audio, identification

[image]
Hi, I found this device lying around somewhere and I have no idea what it is. Can someone help me figure out what it is?

Answer (score 9):

It looks like an IR receiver/extender.  Used to get the receiver out from behind IR blocking glass.

However, it could be an emitter that is used to then drive the IR input of a box that is under control of your PVR/ VCR.  So a IR emitter, but likely the former as it appears to be stuck to a forward facing surface.

Comment: It could be a microphone as well.